# How to get values from all the input's of form in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webapi

this is my form

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Add new customer";
}
<h1>Add new customer</h1>
<form method="post" action ="AddCustomer">
    <input name="customerID" placeholder="Add customer ID"/>
    <input name="customerName" placeholder="Add customer name"/>
    <input name="contactName" placeholder="Add contact name"></input>
    <input name="adress" placeholder="Add adress"></input>      
    <input name="city" placeholder="Add city"></input>
    <input name="postalCode" placeholder="Add postal code"></input>
    <input name="country" placeholder="Add country"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

it sends post request to this action

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Simple")]
 public string AddCustomer([FromBody] string value)
  {
    return value;
  }
```

so how to get values from these inputs for me be able to send post request and create new customer using these values

Retrieving data from this form

Comment: Do you have a "customer" object that matches the structure of this data?  If not, why not?  If you're just looking for tutorials on how to use ASP.NET Web API and similar tools, there are plenty available.  But if you have some specific restrictions or requirements in place and are trying to get around them in some specific way, please clarify the problem.

Comment: so now i would create that object, thanks.To be more specific i wanted to get all these values from these inputs and then save them - like in answer which Misha provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a DTO (data transfer object).

```cs
public class CustomerDto
{
    public GUID CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And then you controller should be:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("AddCustomer")]
public IActionResult AddCustomer([FromForm] CustomerDto customer)
{
    // use customer properties...
}
```

And then in the form add an `enctype`.

```html
<form method="post" action="AddCustomer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```